# Plotting relationship between categorcial variable and Datetime

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Consider a dataframe

```
some_id  timestamp
  a         1.2.2019
  b         2.2.2019
  c         3.2.2019
  a         4.2.2019
  b         5.2.2019
```

Now you can see there are 3 unique ids and among that a and b is associated with 2 timestamps , I want ids to come on x axis and blocks of dates on y axis. How can this be done ? Thank you for your patience. I want this in python using matplotlib or seaborn or any other visualization library. I also appreciate if you can mention a different way of meaningful visualization between these two variables. I  want the figure to look like this below. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to visualize the data with the id's on the x-axis and the dates on the y-axis. Supposing your dates are in the format `day.month.year`.

With `ax.text` you can put text inside the bars, either the date or an other column of interest.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def timestr_to_num(timestr):
    print(datetime.strptime(timestr, '%d.%m.%Y'))
    return mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(timestr, '%d.%m.%Y'))

rows = [['a', '1.2.2019'],
        ['b', '2.2.2019'],
        ['c', '3.2.2019'],
        ['a', '4.2.2019'],
        ['b', '5.2.2019']]
columns = ['some_id', 'timestamp']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=columns)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

xs = list(df['some_id'].unique())
for row in df.itertuples():
    x = xs.index( row.some_id)
    y = timestr_to_num(row.timestamp)
    ax.barh(y, left=x-0.5, width=1, height=1)
    ax.text(x, y, row.timestamp, ha='center', va='center', color='white', fontsize=16)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%Y'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))  # set a tick every hour
ax.set_xlabel('some_id')
ax.set_ylabel('timestamp')
ax.set_xticks(range(len(xs)))
ax.set_xticklabels(xs)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Another idea could be:

```
df.sort_values(by=['some_id', 'timestamp']).groupby(['some_id', 'timestamp']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

But then the dates are in a legend, which might not be suitable if the list is too long.